# DocuSign Envelope Template: Sending to Sender and Multiple Contacts, but Only One Contact Receives It

Tags: docusign

I am encountering an issue while attempting to send the DocuSign Envelope template from the account record. The intention is to send the envelope to both the sender and multiple contacts listed in the Related Lists. However, I am currently facing a problem where only one contact is receiving the envelope. Could anyone kindly guide me on why this might be happening?
[image: Recipients Configuration Envelope Template]

Comment: Have you checked with Docusign support?